# Screen irresponsive when using a gif and a CupertinoDatePicker

Tags: flutter

This is a very surprising issue (Flutter is usually great).
The screen gets completely stuck and not responsive when using a few widgets from Flutter's own library and no additional packages (after about 15-20 seconds).
The problem is consistent when changing the gif to be an asset instead of network, changing the gif itself, and I even tried totally different development environments (Linux desktop to windows laptop) as well!

Minimal code:

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
        // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
        // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
        // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
        // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
        // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
        // is not restarted.
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const BirthdayOnboardingScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class BirthdayOnboardingScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static String routeName = '/birthday_onboarding';

  const BirthdayOnboardingScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _BirthdayOnboardingScreenState createState() =>
      _BirthdayOnboardingScreenState();
}

class _BirthdayOnboardingScreenState extends State<BirthdayOnboardingScreen> {
  DateTime selectedDate = DateTime(1990, 1,
      1);

  final firstDate = DateTime(1900, 1);
  final lastDate = DateTime.now();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;

    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Image.network('https://c.tenor.com/52lufF4B6ogAAAAd/happy-birthday-to-me-my-birthday.gif'),
             Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                  height:

                  screenHeight * 0.18,
                  child: CupertinoDatePicker(
                      mode: CupertinoDatePickerMode.date,
                      initialDateTime: selectedDate,
                      minimumDate: firstDate,
                      maximumDate: lastDate,
                      onDateTimeChanged: (newDate) {
                        setState(() {
                          selectedDate = newDate;
                        });
                      }),
                ),

              ],
            ),

          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

a video demonstrating the issue:

https://youtu.be/rjRlLpoKpTs

Comment: Ran your code on [https://dartpad.dev](https://dartpad.dev) and after that time, it starts slowing down, like if there is a memory problem. Have you tried to run developer tools and looking for memory consumption? And issues should be filed at [https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues)

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/98275 and which developer tools? I've tried  running with flutter run --verbose and there are literally no error messages. It makes sense that it's a memory issue, but I do wonder how. Notice that the gif or the picker by themselves are running fine.

Comment: I see you are (probably) using VSCode to program (video), if you have the Flutter extension installed, on the bottom bar at the right corner you will be able to select which device you want to run, and pressing "f5" on your keyboard you will debug your flutter application through it. Then, when you press "f1" you will have an option ">Flutter: Open DevTools"

Comment: Android studio, but anyways devtools memory tab just draws a flat line so I'm not sure what happens.

Comment: None of the data from DevTools gave you any insight? You could try and run it in Profile mode so your data is actually similar to release